# Unwind Segue Goes Back Too Far

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a `firstViewController` embedded in a `firstNavigationController` that has a modal segue to a new `secondViewController` embedded in another `secondNavigationController`. This new controller performs an unwind segue back to the `firstViewController`

**secondViewController**:

```
- (void) cancelAction{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backHoney" sender:self];
}
```

**firstViewController:**

```
- (IBAction)backToHoney:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender{
}
```

This works but there is a case when another `viewC` embedded in a `Nav` has a modal segue to the `firstViewController`. When the user goes from this `viewC` to the `firstViewController` then to the `secondViewController` and tries to unwind back to the first, it unwinds all the way back to `viewC` instead of the first.

Answer (score 0):

you should use popToviewController instead of unwing segue. you can go to  any viewController of navigation stack by this.

for example,

```
NSArray *viewArr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];   //returs viewcontroller array
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewArr objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
//you can pass different index to go to differen VC
```

You can refer my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824524/programmatically-defining-a-new-navigation-controller-order-stack/36824849#36824849) for more detail.

hope this will help :)

Comment: I need to unwind from `secondNavController` to `firstNavController`. Also passing data. Isn't this just for navigating about all viewControllers within the same NavController? @Lion

Comment: you can use delegate and protocol for pass the data. there is nothing  mandatory to use unwind segue.